# How to update a column based on the values from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as shown below

| SourceCustomerId | HasTaxBenifit | HasCollateral | HasLoan | Selected Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100021 | No | No | No |  |
| 100022 | No | No | Yes |  |
| 100023 | No | Yes | No |  |
| 100024 | No | Yes | Yes |  |
| 100025 | Yes | No | No |  |
| 100026 | Yes | No | Yes |  |
| 100027 | Yes | Yes | No |  |
| 100028 | YEs | Yes | Yes |  |

How do, I achieve this output?

| SourceCustomerId | HasTaxBenifit | HasCollateral | HasLoan | Selected Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100021 | No | No | No |  |
| 100022 | No | No | Yes | Loan |
| 100023 | No | Yes | No | Collateral |
| 100024 | No | Yes | Yes | Collateral,Loan |
| 100025 | Yes | No | No | Tax Benifit |
| 100026 | Yes | No | Yes | Tax Benifit, Loan |
| 100027 | Yes | Yes | No | Tax Benifit, Collateral |
| 100028 | YEs | Yes | Yes | Tax Benifit, Collateral, Loan |

Comment: With an `UPDATE` and a `CASE` expressions? What have *you* tried? Why didn't it work? Why do you want to store delimited data at all, it breaks one of the basic principles of normal form.

Comment: Please provide more details and what you have tried?  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Complete aside, you've spelled Benefit wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CONCAT_WS` and [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)(no need for update):

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD SelectedProduct AS
    CONCAT_WS(', ',
              IIF(HasTaxBenefit='Yes', 'TaxBenefit', NULL),
              IIF(HasCollateral='Yes', 'Collateral', NULL),
              IIF(HasLoan='Yes', 'Loan', NULL)
             );
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=656ea1207c0dd73109e6f88d87ba4b84)**

Comment: To clear my doubt, Do we really need ALTER TABLE ? Based on my understanding it should be used to only change or modify table structure right?

Comment: If you want to have it always behave this way, then yes table has to be altered. Alternatively you could use `CONCAT_WS...` in a select statement, view or in update statement `UPDATE... SET SelectedProduct = CONCAT_WS ...`. Using computed column makes this logic "pernament"

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE yourTable SET SelectedProduct=(CASE
WHEN Condition1 then Result1
ELSE
...
END)
```